# Python while loop analysis serving with Flask Socket.IO

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio, eventlet

I'm curious about how would one solves the following issue better the current state I am in right now.

I propose the following architecture:

### Architecture

The idea is to use multi-threading for this task, by running the Flask Socket.IO in a thread and have a while loop in another thread that can emit on demand to all connected clients.

> project
>
> - main.py
> - analyze.py
> - webapp.py

### `analyze.py`

The actual program will grab stuff from a file every few seconds and if something is changed, it will analyze its contents and the result will be pushed via Socket.IO to all of the clients.

```
import webapp


def analyze():
    while True:
        message_object = analyzeStuff()
        webapp.send_message(message_object)
```

### `webapp.py`

Here we implement the actual Flask Socket.IO endpoints. For simplicity, here is a small snapshot of what's going on on my side:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
socket = SocketIO(app)

@socket.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print('Client connected')
    pass

@socket.on('disconnect')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')
    pass

def send_message(data):
    socket.emit('message', data)
    # print('sending message "{}".'.format(data))
```

### `main.py`

In the main Thread we open up the Socket.IO thread then we run our analysis.

I'm using `eventlet.monkey_patch()` (though I'm not sure what it does exactly) to be able to call `.emit` from another Thread than the one with the Socket.IO server.

```
import analyze
import webapp
import threading

import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Start the server
    webapp_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_web_app)
    webapp_thread.start()

    # Run the Analyze loop
    analyze.analyze()
```

---

The current state is working fine, tough I am currently having some issues fitting this into an apache2 wsgi-mode server, which I'm currently working on.

Even so, this looks ugly and I can't stop thinking there should be a better way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this work at all? You are using evenlet, so everything runs in a single thread. Isn't your analyze loop blocking your application?

Comment: Yeah, it has something to do with `eventlet.monkey_patch()` which actually lets `Socket.IO` to detach from the main thread.

Comment: I suggest you read up on how eventlet works. An eventlet application only has a main thread, there is no detaching. Multitasking happens cooperatively within the main thread.

Comment: Have you even tried the snippet? It works just fine.

Comment: I have seen the snippet, of course. If your `analyzeStuff()` function takes, say, 5 seconds to produce a result, your web server is going to be blocked and unresponsive for those 5 seconds.

Comment: You can test with a `time.sleep(5)` and it works fine. It does for me.

Comment: Using `time.sleep(5)` would not reproduce the problem that I'm talking about, and this goes back to the way things work in eventlet, which is different than threads. But in any case, clearly you are satisfied with your solution. I pointed out something that I'm pretty sure is wrong, but if you are not interested I'll leave you alone.

Comment: As I said before, I'm not stating that I'm right and I'm sure this is not the way to do things as it is very ugly indeed, but for my use-case, it works just fine. Still, I do not approve of this method myself. Can you propose another solution of using Flask-Socket.IO in a multi-threading program where I can `emit` from other threads?

Comment: Looking through Flask-SocketIO examples found this: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/app.py that indeed proposes a better way to do things and is in line with what you were saying above. Thanks for the help @Miguel. Now I need to wrap my head around how to serve this with mod_wsgi.